# WPF : Custom bubbling routed event never handled/catched

Tags: wpf, event-handling, custom-controls, routed-events

I have a Usercontrol (UC1) which contains a list of other UCs (UC2), i want to raise an event in my UC2 when something is modified in it and catch it in UC1, so i declared it like that :

**In my UC2 Class :**

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent LiaisonModifieeEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
    "ModificationOccured", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(UC2));
```

**In the consructor of my UC1 Class :**

```
this.AddHandler(UC2.LiaisonModifieeEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ModificationOccuredEvent_Handler), true);
```

**And the declaration of my handling method**

```
private void ModificationOccuredEvent_Handler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        SaveCablingLinkButton.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

Seems that i'm missing something, but i can't see what, the event never is catched in UC1.

**EDIT** : i forgot to mention the raising part

**Somewhere in UC2**

```
RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(UC2.LiaisonModifieeEvent, this));
```

Comment: What you posted seems to be in order. Can you also post how you raise you event?

Comment: Are you wiring the UC1 handler after UC2 receives the loaded event?

Comment: @dkozl : done :)
Garry Vass : yep the loading of UC2s happens after the construction of UC1

Comment: @Sicha: I've just copied your code and my `UC1` catches event raised in any `UC2` control as expected

Comment: @Sicha if you need to compare your code with mine then [here](http://db.tt/lIafuybM) it is. Your code should work.

Comment: Well, i thought my UC2 were created when i added my handler but it seems that it was not. Thanks guys for your time, it is solved :)